Why is the "If statement" getting skipped?
I am trying to do a QuickSort assignment for my Algorithms course and for some reason that I don't know, I can't figure out why my code is skipping the QuickSort portion (surrounded by "//") and it is frustrating me.
The code's goal is to Rearrange the vector so that the negatives are in the front, then zero, and then the positive numbers.
How code works right now is that I am given an unsorted array (which is "u") from main(), and I partition the array into 2 subarrays with the middle as my pivot. Then, I am sorting the code using Quicksort, using the first element as my pivot for that specific subarray.
However, when I was debugging and I set up breakpoints before and after the "if (right < i)" statement section, which is the Quicksort portion, it would skip the "if (right < i)" statement section and move on.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void orderVector(vector<double>& u) {
    if (u[0] < u[u.size() - 1]) {
        int pivotIndex = (u.size() / 2);
        vector<double> s_lower, s_upper;
        for (int i = 0; i < pivotIndex; i++) {
            s_lower.push_back(u[i]);
        }
        for (int i = pivotIndex + 1; i < u.size(); i++) {
            s_upper.push_back(u[i]);
        }

        // Order the vectors
        int left, i;
        // Lower
        left = 0;
        double pivot = s_lower[left];
        i = left;
        int right = (s_lower.size() - 1);

// Quicksort Portion skipped
        if (right < i) {
            while (pivot <= s_lower[i] && pivot >= s_lower[right]) {
                i++;
                right--;
                swap(s_lower[i], s_lower[right]);
            }
        }
// (end of portion skipped)
        swap(s_lower[left], s_lower[right]);

        /*
        vector<double> sorted;
        sorted.insert(sorted.end(), s_lower.begin(), s_lower.end());
        sorted.insert(sorted.end(), s_upper.begin(), s_upper.end());*/

        for (auto x : s_lower)
            cout << x << " ";
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<double> unsorted = {-1, 2, -3, 4, 5, 6, -7, 8, 9};
    orderVector(unsorted);
}


If it skips the if (right < i) then right is probably not less than i.

Did you try stepping through the code line by line with a debugger to see what the logic is actually doing and where it deviates from your expectations?

I can't figure out why my code is skipping the QuickSort portion (surrounded by "//") and it is frustrating me. As a programmer it's essential to understand how to use your debugger. If you had properly stepped through the code 1 line at a time looking at the variables and flow after each individual line was executed you would have quickly seen that right < i is false and there was no mystery at all in why this is the case. I am saying this not trying to be harsh but to help you. Learning how to debug is extremely important / essential to be an effective developer.

When asked to implement an algorithm for a course, look up the algorithm. In the case of quicksort, wikipedia documents the major partition schemes very well and odds are good if you do anything that isn't covered, you may have a sorting algorithm, but the instructor may reduce your grade because you haven't implemented quicksort. Side note: I find Hoare partitioning easier to implement

"I set up breakpoints before and after the 'if (right < i)' statement section, [...] it would skip the 'if (right < i)' statement section and move on." -- So you were in a debugger, and you had the program paused at the exact moment something unexpected was about to occur. That means it was time to check the values of your variables. What were the values of right and i while you were at this breakpoint?

As an aside, u[u.size() - 1] is also known as u.back(). This is a related to push_back, which creates a new back.

FYI, the size() function returns an unsigned quantity.  Your other variables are signed int.  The issue is range.  Converting a large unsigned quantity to a signed quantity may result in a very negative number.

The short answer is that the code is skipped because right < i is false.
Tracing the code though you have a vector size 9 in main which means that the vector u in your function is the same size. Now
pivotIndex = u.size() / 2;

i.e. pivotIndex equals 4. So four numbers are pushed onto s_lower, i.e. s_lower.size() equals 4. Then
int right = (s_lower.size() - 1);

so right equals 3.
Now consider i, we have left = 0; then i = left; therefore i equals zero.
This means that right < i is false and therefore the code that you indicated is skipped. Put another way the code is behaving exactly as you would expect. Now clearly the code is not behaving as you want it to, you presumably want it to perform a quicksort. But looking at the code I think you must have some misunderstandings about how quicksort works, because the code doesn't do anything close to a quicksort. So maybe the best thing to do is discard this code and look at the quicksort algorithm again.
One of the features of quicksort is that it is possible to do it in place. This means that you don't need any extra vectors apart from the one you are sorting. So as soon as you decided to use s_lower and s_upper you were going in the wrong direction. Another feature of quicksort is that it is a recursive algorithm and there is no recursion in your code (although maybe you intended to add that later).
